# Swift combining predicates LogicalType AND OR

Tags: swift, nspredicate

How can i combine a mix AND OR condition in Swift predicate. I have a following query

```
 Select * from tblTemp where dept == 1 && (subdept == 11 || subdept == 12)
```

I can write two predicate with same operator but don't know how to combine them

```
    let deptPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "dept == %@", 1)
    let subdeptPredicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "subdept = %@", 11)
    let subdeptPredicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "subdept = %@", 12)
    let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.and, subpredicates: [deptPredicate, subdeptPredicate1])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSCompoundPredicate` is a subclass of `NSPredicate`, which means
that the result of 
`NSCompoundPredicate(type:subpredicates:)` can be used in another compound
predicate.

Note however that the `%@` format placeholder expects an `NSObject`
instance:

```
let deptPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "dept == %@", 1 as NSNumber)
let subdeptPredicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "subdept = %@", 11 as NSNumber)
let subdeptPredicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "subdept = %@", 12 as NSNumber)

let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or,
                                      subpredicates: [subdeptPredicate1, subdeptPredicate2])

let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and,
                                       subpredicates: [deptPredicate, orPredicate])
```

Alternatively, use the `%ld` format for integers:

```
let deptPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "dept == %ld", 1)
// ... etc.
```

There are also convenience initializers:

```
let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates:
    [subdeptPredicate1, subdeptPredicate2])

let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
    [deptPredicate, orPredicate])
```

Compound predicates are very useful to combine a dynamic set of
conditions at runtime. On the other hand, if only the *values* change
then you can simply use "AND" and "OR" within the predicate
format string:

```
NSPredicate(format: "dept == %ld AND (subdept = %ld OR subdept = %ld)", 1, 11, 12)
```

Finally note that you can use the `#keyPath` directive with the
`%K` placeholder, so that the compiler fills in the correct property
name (thus reducing the chance of typographical errors):

```
let deptPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %ld", #keyPath(MyEntity.dept), 1)
```

Comment: If the numbers are fixed you can put them in the format `"dept == 1 AND (subdept = 11 OR subdept = 12)"`.